# spread operator function call ambiguity

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

When converting java StringTokenizer to kotlin split I'm unable to supply a list of character delimiters:

```
val delim : Array<Char> = arrayOf('(',')','{','}','[',/*many more...*/)
sourceExpr.split(delimiters=*delim,ignoreCase=false,limit=0)
```

Here kotlin compiler for some reason is unable to disambiguate between `split(vararg String,...)` and `split(vararg Char,...)`. Questions:

1. Is is a bug?
2. Is there cast workaround?
3. How did ancient pre-Collection era vararg concept infiltrated modern programming language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue isn't disambiguation but rather an incorrect type. In Kotlin, an `Array<Char>` is equivalent to a Java `Character[]`. That means that when you use `*delim`, you're actually creating a `vararg Character` (instead of `vararg Char`).

Instead, you should prefer the primitive-specific `CharArray`:

```
val delim: CharArray = charArrayOf('(', ')', '{', '}')
sourceExpr.split(delimiters = *delim, ignoreCase = false, limit = 0)
```